# How to add a QQuickItem extension as a child to another QQuickItem extension?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am currently working on setting up a C++ factory for Qt Quick. I need to be able to add the children generated by the factory to another custom QQuickItem, like this:

```
class Bar : public QQuickItem {
    Q_Object

    Bar(QQuickItem * parent = 0) : QQuickItem(parent) {
        // Generate some config called barConfig
        QQuickItem * newChild = FooFactory(barConfig);
        // Add child here?
    }
}
```

While in reality, there is a `BarModel` governing the config for the factory, that seems to be irrelevant here. So, how would I do add my `newChild` as a child of the `Bar` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setParentItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop):

```
Bar(QQuickItem * parent = 0) : QQuickItem(parent) {
    // Generate some config called barConfig
    QQuickItem * newChild = FooFactory(barConfig);
    newChild->setParentItem(this);
}
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to instantiating with `QQuickItem * newChild = new Foo(this);`, where `Foo` passes on `this` to the super constructor? Or does `setParentItem` do something more?

Comment: @iHowell  
they are the same, only in my example, establishing it later.